# How to find top most Activity launched in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, intercept, pooling

I need a way to detect the active Activity without pooling.

The right way is to have a Service that listens for Activities launching in a continuous way.

BUT, I do not want to do pooling since it drains the battery.
I have tried `READ_LOGS` permission, but it seems that I have to have ROOT access, which I do not have/need.

I am thinking that I need a kind of Broadcast Receiver and listen for Apps changes like this:

```
ActivityChangerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to get the list of running tasks without root

Comment: by active activity, do you mean current activity?

Comment: @JayDangar I mean the launch detection of an Activity

Comment: in your own app or in all apps

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes it is using         android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS and     UsageStatsManager

Comment: @TimCastelijns since it will be a Service, it is for all apps

Comment: yeah you're not going to be able to do that. Imagine some random app being able to monitor everything you do on your phone

Comment: There should be a hack using reflection...

Comment: @Duna What you want to do sounds so malicious

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after doing couple of days of research. It is possible!

The entry key is using: AccessibilityService class service and register for "Retrieve Window Content" permissions.